# Zero-padded h264 in mdat

Tags: h.264, mp4

I'd like to do some stuff with h.264 data recorded from Android phone.

My colleague told me there should be 4 bytes right after `mdat` wich specifies NALU size, then one byte with NALU metadata and then the raw data, and then (after NALU size), another 4 bytes with another NALU size and so on.

But I have a lot of zeros right after `mdat`:

```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```

Before `mdat` atom are just `ftyp` `mp42`, `isom` `mp42` and `free` atoms. All other atoms (`moov`, ...) are at the end of the file (that's what Android does, when it writes to socket and not to the file). But If necessary, I've got PPS and SPS from other file with same camera and encoder settings recorded just a seond before this, just to get those PPS and SPS data.

So how exactly can i get NALUs from that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The moov atom contains information required to parse the mdat. Without it the mdat has little value. For instance, the first NALU does not need to start at the begining of the mdat, It can start anywhere within the mdat. The byte it starts at is recorded in (I believe) the stco box. If the file has audio, you will find audio and video mixed within mdat with no way to determine what is what without the chunk offsets. In addition, if the video has B frames, there is no way to determine render order without the cts, again only available in the moov. And Technically, the nalu size does not need to be 4 bytes and you cant know that without the moov. I recommend not used mp4. Use a streamable container such as ts or flv. Now if you can make some assumption about the code that is producing the file; Like the chunk offset is always the same, and there is no b frames, you can hard code these values. But is not guaranteed to work after a software update.

Comment: Well, my code works (lots of NALUs of type 1, sometimes type 5) 80 % of the time. But somethimes, there are those zeros at the begining, and it goes full banana. Unfortunately, I can't easily use other containers then mpeg4 and 3gpp in Android. And I know there is just video in `mdat`.

Comment: Then I think you need to skip the container totally and use the raw output buffers form MediaCodec.

Comment: I would, if I could. But we want to support Android 2.3, so I have to use `MediaRecorder`, create `ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()` and pass one file descriptor to `MediaRecorder` and another to processing thread and read from the pipe. And this zero padded binary is what I sometimes get.

Comment: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/blob/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/rtp/H264Packetizer.java#L244 Slightly modified version of this is how I solved it. And it seems to work. :)

Comment: Awesome, Glad you got a solution to work. I Generally try to provide the generic solution in my answers. Sometimes its possible to develop specific solutions by making some assumptions.